# Angular Grid / table with clickable cases

Tags: angular, row, clickable

I need to make a table / grid with on the left side the dates and the top side the different users. In each case I want to show/set the activity that the user is doing at the regarding dates. Moreover I would like to have the possibility to click on a case and change directly the activity

I need to make this using Angular or Javascript and I am wondering if there is not yet an existing component making the job? If possible no JQuery involved

Answer (score 0):

It seams to be simple table with specific data for your case. You just need to set column names for specific user with first column empty or date/user name and first column set dates for it. Simple maping should do the job. Here is table you can use [Material Table](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fz7mf9?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)